# ASP.NET Core - JWT authorization always throws 401

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, authorization

I know this is a common issue, yet as I searched the similiar topics I couldn't find any solution.

I've created a simple API with JWT authorization, however, after adding `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` tag to my Controller, every request (even with JWT Token added in Swagger) throws 401.

JWT is configured like this:

```
var jwtSettings = new JwtSettings();
        configuration.Bind(nameof(jwtSettings), jwtSettings);
        services.AddSingleton(jwtSettings);

        services.AddScoped<IIdentityService, IdentityService>();

        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jwtSettings.Secret)),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                RequireExpirationTime = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true
            };
        });
```

Startup class looks like this:

```
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        var swaggerOptions = new SwaggerOptions();
        Configuration.GetSection(nameof(SwaggerOptions)).Bind(swaggerOptions);

        app.UseSwagger(option =>
        {
            option.RouteTemplate = swaggerOptions.JsonRoute;
        });
        app.UseSwaggerUI(option =>
        {
            option.SwaggerEndpoint(swaggerOptions.UIEndpoint, swaggerOptions.Description);
        });
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        //this is correct order
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
```

And token generating method looks like this:

```
public async Task<AuthenticationResult> RegisterAsync(string email, string password)
    {
        var existingUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
        if (existingUser != null)
        {
            return new AuthenticationResult
            {
                Errors = new[] { "User with this e-mail address already exists" }
            };
        }
        var newUser = new IdentityUser
        {
            Email = email,
            UserName = email
        };
        var createdUser = await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, password);
        if (!createdUser.Succeeded)
        {
            return new AuthenticationResult
            {
                Errors = createdUser.Errors.Select(x => x.Description)
            };
        }

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_jwtSettings.Secret);
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, newUser.Email),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, newUser.Email),
                new Claim("id", newUser.Id)
            }),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(2),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };

        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        return new AuthenticationResult
        {
            Success = true,
            Token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token)
        };
    }
```

Now when my Controller will have the Authorize tag:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class PostsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IPostService _postService;
    public PostsController(IPostService postService)
    {
        _postService = postService;
    }

    [HttpGet(ApiRoutes.Posts.GetAll)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
    {
        return Ok(await _postService.GetPostsAsync()); //returns all Posts from db
    }
}
```

It always throws 401. The token itself after decoding by jwt.io looks fine:

```
//header 
{
  "alg": "HS256"
}
//payload
{
  "sub": "john_doe@mail.com",
  "jti": "284db32d-6cc3-4532-96cf-55d0df9c3606",
  "email": "john_doe@mail.com",
  "id": "e76b112a-55bd-4c4b-832b-32ee7f6b1445",
  "nbf": 1641585546,
  "exp": 1641592746,
  "iat": 1641585546
}
//signature
HMACSHA256(
  base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +
  base64UrlEncode(payload),
  your-256-bit-secret
)
```

My appsettings:

```
  "JwtSettings": {
    "Secret": "sYwxnmRz6PpTnoQC7Fj3oQdqLcFtQEdI" //Im aware of not sharing this but this api is just for fun
  },
  "SwaggerOptions": {
    "JsonRoute": "swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json",
    "Description": "ShareThoughtAPI",
    "UIEndpoint": "v1/swagger.json"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I think I've done everything by the book. I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARvsBUBioT0&list=PLUOequmGnXxOgmSDWU7Tl6iQTsOtyjtwU&index=11) and did everything the same, yet the issue persists. I've ensured the correct order of Authorization, Routing and Authentication in Startup class and JWT config is basically copy-pasted. I've read the code 100 times and still can't find anything wrong with it. What am I missing?

Comment: Refer this article step by step Asp.net core JWT authentication https://codepedia.info/jwt-authentication-in-aspnet-core-web-api-token

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to find the answer to it. My mistake was nowhere close where I was looking for.

My previous Swagger configuration looked like this:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(x =>
            {
                x.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo { Title = "ShareThoughtAPI", Version = "v1 " });
                var security = new OpenApiSecurityRequirement();
                x.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Description = "JWT Authorization header using the bearer scheme",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
                });
                x.AddSecurityRequirement(security);
            });
```

However the proper way which now works should look like this:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(x =>
            {
                x.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo { Title = "ShareThoughtAPI", Version = "v1 " });
                x.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Description = "JWT Authorization header using the bearer scheme",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
                });
                x.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Id = "Bearer",
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
                            }
                        },
                        new List<string>()
                    }
                });
            });
```

Now sending the request from Postman or Fiddler works and config token in Swagger doesn't throw 401 all the time.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in .NET6. Couldn't make it work without Audience and Issuer attributes, though.

Token generation:

```
var plainTextSecurityKey = "This is secret";

var signingKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(
    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainTextSecurityKey));

var signingCredentials = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(signingKey,
    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

// -------------------------

var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "myemail@myprovider.com"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator"),
            }, "Custom");

var securityTokenDescriptor = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenDescriptor()
{
    Audience = "http://my.website.com",
    Issuer = "http://my.tokenissuer.com",

    Subject = claimsIdentity,
    SigningCredentials = signingCredentials
};

var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var plainToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(securityTokenDescriptor);
var signedAndEncodedToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(plainToken);

Console.WriteLine(signedAndEncodedToken);
```

Token validation:

```
builder.Services
.AddAuthentication(cfg =>
{
    cfg.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    cfg.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
{
    var plainTextSecurityKey = "This is secret";

    var signingKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainTextSecurityKey));

    var signingCredentials = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(signingKey,
        Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

    cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {            
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateIssuer   = false,
        IssuerSigningKey = signingKey            
    };

    // this is useful as you can see the actual issue
    cfg.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = async context =>
        {
            var ex = context.Exception;
        }
    };
});
```

Note how the `OnAuthenticationFailed` is attached so that when there's a problem, you can see the exception. Beware, however, that the actual issue can be nested deep in `InnerException` chain of the exception.

Comment: I copied your token generation code to my "RegisterAsync" method, and your token validation to my Startup, with a difference that I take my secret from appsettings and it doesn't work. so I guess I am messing up something elsewhere.

Comment: What the exception says?

Comment: There are no exceptions, it just throws 401.

Comment: Sounds like your `Authorization: Bearer {token}` is not among client headers.

Comment: And how can I fix it? You can see all my code above.

Comment: You didn't show the client code (the Javascript or whatever else is your client) at all.

Comment: I am using only API right now, without any client side. The 401 is thrown by Swagger.

Comment: I am inserting in Swagger the Bearer {token} which should make my endpoints accessible, since it already adds this to the header, however controller throws 401. So I think my configuration is messed up somewhere, but I'm not sure where.

Comment: Could you switch to another tool like Fiddler? Just make a request with your browser and it will be visible in Fiddler with 401 reply. Then, drag the request to Composer and add the header there. If it still fails, strip your code to a bare minimum. If it still fails, I could possibly create a tiny solution and share it somewhere. Let me know how's your progress.

Comment: Used a fiddler just like you asked. I added key "Authorization" and value "Bearer {token}" with token generated by the code above and it's still 401. I can't really strip the code to bare minimum because it already IS a bare minimum. It's a simple API with JWT config added and Entity Framework Core.

Comment: I created a [repo](https://github.com/virouzrx/ShareThoughtProject/tree/master/ShareThoughtProject) with the API if that can provide any help.

Comment: This gives 404 on GitHub.

Comment: My bad, I forgot Github automatically makes repos private. I've changed it to public now so it should be visible by now.

Comment: Stripped down your code by removing the database and identity stuff but the registration controller and post controller are there. Also, changed your Jwt service startup to mine and changed .NET5 -> .NET6. Added readme.md that shows actual requests and replies from Fiddler. This definitely works, returns the data with the token and 401 without. [Download here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a2fnK4sO1vz2jTbPXKLuqzHMtvk3nUmh/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you for all your work and help!

Comment: Good to hear the issue is resolved, it had to be unrelated to the actual service and removing all the unnecessary stuff helped.